# When cloning a repository from GIT to a local directory, one of the subfolder clones empty

Tags: repository

I need to set up VIVIDUS to run some automated tests located in the repository.

When I start proceeding with the initial system setup from scrach using this link https://docs.vividus.dev/vividus/latest/getting-started.html#_setup_test_project at the step of BUILD YOU PROJECT I can't proceed since the gradlew build command doesn't find a file to execute (gradlew.bat) because when cloning a repository from GIT to a local directory the mentioned folder is cloned empty, therefore the file is missing [command line screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YiQj.png).

Answer (score 0):

vividus-build-system is a submodule for the repo you are trying to clone. you need to clone that repo as well.

more info here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot, this makes sence!